# print zipped generator results

Tags: python

any idea how to print

```
(([0.2, 0.6], [0.5, 0.8]), "10 11 {'chocolate': 10}")
(([0.0, 0.6], [0.8, 0.5]), "10 12 {'chocolate': 10}")
```

as..

```
0.2  0.6  0.5  0.8  10  11 chocolate 10
0.0  0.6  0.8  0.5  10  12 chocolate 10
```

I have also manage to coerce it to (ignoring chocolate for now):

```
(([0.2, 0.6], [0.5, 0.8]), '10 11 10')
(([0.0, 0.6], [0.8, 0.5]), '10 12 10')
```

if this is easier to turn into

```
0.2  0.6  0.5  0.8  10  11  10
0.0  0.6  0.8  0.5  10  12  10
```

tried what i found on other questions here but such as

```
      print  '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,tuple(chain(*i)))) for i in s)
```

bit this results in words and last elements looking like

```
 c        h      o       c        o        l      a      t    e
```

I'm still trying....

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you actually want as the output. is ``chocolate'`` a typo or do you actually want that ``'``?

Comment: sorry new to this too, corrected.

Comment: Is that dict meant to be a part of the string?

Comment: yes its the product of zip.  I was trying to use zip to put  `([0.2, 0.6], [0.5, 0.8])`   and `10 11 {'chocolate': 10}` together as it is incredibly useful shortcut.

Comment: This is not a very good form of organization for printing like this...

Comment: maybe I can improve this jamylak

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your data is

```
>>> spam=(([0.2, 0.6], [0.5, 0.8]), "10 11 {'chocolate': 10}")
```

You can simply do

```
>>> print str(spam).translate(None,"([]){},\"'")
0.2 0.6 0.5 0.8 10 11 chocolate: 10
```

If you want to tabify your data

```
>>> print str(spam).translate(None,"([]){},\"'").replace(' ','\t')
0.2 0.6 0.5 0.8 10  11  chocolate:  10
>>>
```

And if you are fine with braces '{' and the colon ':' in your final output you may also do

```
>>> ''.join(map(str,list(itertools.chain(*list(itertools.chain(*spam))))))
"0.20.60.50.810 11 {'chocolate': 10}"
```

or what you were currently doing

```
>>> print ''.join(map(str,list(itertools.chain(*list(itertools.chain(*spam))))))
0.20.60.50.810 11 {'chocolate': 10}
>>>
```

which is similar to what your expression was trying to achieve, but adding `tab` and `newline` with the `join` ruined it.

But simplicity and readability wise I feel, the former approach would be better

Comment: even better: print str(spam).translate(None,"\"([]),")

Comment: Presuming that the data can't contain those characters.

Comment: this removes the the "\"([]),"  but also loses the formatting i.e. columns as required though

Comment: @user1322296: If your want your data as column split it again on space and join it with tab unless your data can contain spaces.

Comment: I need to remove braces so i guess i need to learn column split and join with tab code.  ooof

Comment: @user1322296: See my update, where I mentioned how to tabify your data

Comment: see it now! Boom Abhijit, perfect.

Comment: but why wont it print in columns to text file!

`open("file.txt", "w").write('\n'.join(str(spam).translate(None,"([]){},\"'").replace(' ','\t')))`

I really suck at this...